# How to make every items of a swipe listview opened by default?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using 47deg/android-swipelistview library i need to open all the items by default without any touch event
i tried using `listView.openAnimate(int position)` but it returns null pointer exception since there is no touch event. I jus wanted to create swipe list effect like secret app [image]

[image]

Comment: did you got any solution? me too have question like this..